# Passing Decimals with Protobuf across services

Tags: decimal, protocol-buffers

We have proto messages that ideally would contain a decimal as a part of the message.  This proto file is being used by both a Java and a .NET client.

Since we cannot use decimal, what would the recommended approach be for passing these values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many significant digits?

If you know ahead of time, you could use a [fixed-point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) representation, e.g. an integer which is treated as units of 10<sup>-6</sup> or whatever is most appropriate.

If not, well, there's string…